# Asp.net VB Android Phone Upload <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net

I have used  in a asp.net vb page.

It opens great and takes a nice picture.

How do I get it to download to the server rather than save it on the phone?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I missed the tag  "<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"   />"